# WNDPROC documentation

Tags: c#, winforms

I was reading some tutorials and I met the following structure:

```
protected override void WndProc( ref Message m )
{
    ...

    base.WndProc( ref m );
}
```

and for example:

```
private const int WM_DWMCOMPOSITIONCHANGED = 0x31e;
```

what s the meaning of `0x31e`. some documentation for it?

Comment: You can clearly see that it's assigned to a field called `WM_DWMCOMPOSITIONCHANGED`. Why not search for that instead of `0x31e`? In fact, did you search at all before asking?

Comment: I am interested in this kind of numbers...

Comment: And I want a reference about this numbers...

Comment: @Victor what kind of numbers do you mean? Hexadecimal constants? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: I mean constants for WndProc...

Comment: @Victor sorry, I misunderstood you. I updated my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the value of the constant you highlighted.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The actual hexadecimal value has no special meaning other than that it identifies the `WM_DWMCOMPOSITIONCHANGED` message.

There are many other window messages in the Windows API - all messages that start with `WM_` and then some more. You can open `winuser.h` and look for them but you'll have to read the individual message documentations to learn what they do. `winuser.h` only contains the declarations of the constants.